# How to open source an android application

Tags: android, open-source

I recently finished an android application that I put on the play store.
I wish to put it on github / bitbucket in case anyone is interested by it.

There is an ad banner, so I stored my public key in the strings.xml file. How should I handle it ?

I already added a "flavour" in order to be able to generate an apk without ads.

Additionally what kind of similar precautions should I take before releasing it in the wild ?

Comment: This would make a great question on [Open Source Stack Exchange](//opensource.stackexchange.com) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not upload any API keys or alike to any GitHub repository since it's going to be against most of the Terms and Conditions of a lot of providers, including GitHub itself I think.

To solve this, you could put a placeholder in the place where the people should put their own API key and upload that file to the repository, for example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY">PUT YOUR API KEY HERE</string>
</resources>
```

---

You should also start thinking about [licensing your code](http://choosealicense.com/).

> Open source licenses are licenses that comply with the Open Source Definition — in brief, they allow software to be freely used, modified, and shared. To be approved by the Open Source Initiative (also known as the OSI), a license must go through the Open Source Initiative's license review process.

There are a lot of different licenses, including:

- Apache License 2.0
- BSD 3-Clause "New" or "Revised" license
- BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" or "FreeBSD" license
- GNU General Public License (GPL)
- GNU Library or "Lesser" General Public License (LGPL)
- MIT license
- Mozilla Public License 2.0
- Common Development and Distribution License
- Eclipse Public License

Check out [this link](https://opensource.org/licenses) to see more about these licenses.

---

And, yes you can still benefit from your own ads using Open Source, as in the [opensource.org](https://opensource.org/faq#commercial) website is mentioned:

*Can Open Source software be used for commercial purposes?*

> Absolutely. All Open Source software can be used for commercial purpose; the Open Source Definition guarantees this. You can even sell Open Source software.

Comment: I thought about the placeholder, but if figured that I might I would have to replace it by the real value when building an update and that I might forget to remove it before commiting. Am I missing something there ?

Comment: You can create a changelist in Android Studio, to let it know that you want to ignore certain files during commits. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/changelist.html

Comment: If you still forget it you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit